# How to play music when "tab key" is pressed in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, mp3

I want to be able to play a mp3 file when the tab key is pressed on a keyboard.

I am making a number system for a restaurant and when a number is entered and <kbd>tab</kbd> is pressed, it will make a noise which will draw attention to the numbers.

Thanks!

My current code is this. It doesn't work... Please correct me!

```
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

      function checkKeyPressed(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == "9") {
          //Play Music
          document.getElementById('aud').play()
        } 
      }
    </script>
    <audio src="music.mp3" id="aud">
      <p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
    </audio>
```

I also made it hidden in css and the music file is in the same folder... It is not working...

Comment: I'd try using the blur() event: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Javascript` Keyboard Events using `addEventListener` in `Javascript`. The `keyCode` "9" represents the *tab* key.
Examples are shown at this webpage:
http://www.kirupa.com/html5/keyboard_events_in_javascript.htm

**Javascript**:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == "9") {
        //Play Music
        document.getElementById('yourAudioTag').play()
    }
}
```

**HTML**: For playing the music, it's easy if you create an `<audio>` element like this:

```
<audio src="dingdong.mp3" id="yourAudioTag">
<p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
```

**CSS**: add the property `display: none;` so that it isn't visible to the user.

```
#yourAudioTag
{
display: none;
}
```

**JS Event Listener**:
`document.getElementById('yourAudioTag').play();`

Comment: What is the first line of code? I get the function but not the first line.. This is a great start though.

Comment: Read my edited response above on the event listener. Please check my response if you accept it so that others can view it. Thanks.

Comment: I can play music by? the video file name will be dingdong.mp3. Would I place this code in the //Play Music section? How will I put this code in there?

Comment: Reread the HTML section. I suggest you create an audio tag with your music path in it, and use JS to target the element's id as I showed in the Javascript Section of my response (Yes, in the //Play Music section)

Comment: btw, do i have to connect jquery? Does this function use jquery or is it plain javascript? I do not have jquery connected...

Comment: It's obviously plain javascript.